# Displaying the elements in an array twice using single ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the code in below link.
http://jsfiddle.net/96dgL1ga/

As you can see, I have used the below code two times to display the output.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="track in machine.noteMatrix2">
    <td ng-repeat="step in track">
      <div ng-model="step.value">
        {{step.value}}
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I achieve the same output by coding only once.

Comment: You can just have a list of steps and then do a ng-repeat on it.

Comment: can you explain more in detail

Comment: You can map on a single list, but the mapper (or a filter) will has two loops